# Log4net Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I have a custom log4net appender that looks like this:

```
public class MyAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            if (loggingEvent.Level == Level.Error || loggingEvent.Level == Level.Fatal)
            {
                DoWork(RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // silently fail 
        }
    }
}
```

Every now and then, I'll see this exception in the output:

```
log4net:ERROR Exception while logging
System.Threading.LockRecursionException: Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.
   at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLockCore(TimeoutTracker timeout)
   at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLock(TimeoutTracker timeout)
   at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.EnterReadLock()
   at log4net.Util.ReaderWriterLock.AcquireReaderLock()
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.CallAppenders(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.ForcedLog(Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, Level level, Object message, Exception exception)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Log(Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, Level level, Object message, Exception exception)
```

The appender seems to be working fine and my app does not show any errors but these messages are soo annoying. I like clean running software and this is not clean =(

Is my appender implementation ok? Is there some configuration I can include to avoid this error? The closest answer I can find from the gooogs is from this bug report [log4net bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-418). I'm not calling GetAppenders so it doesn't apply to my use case. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: What does `DoWork` do?

Comment: @Rob, publishs the error to a service bus

Comment: Does it ever fail? (What I'm getting at is that `DoWork` might itself log something)

Comment: @Rob Good idea, I'll investigate this.

Comment: I just got bit by this too, any luck @Drew?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, this occurred when my `Appender` was calling code that was logging. Thus, there was recursive logging occurring. This is visualised below:

```
-> Appender -> MyClassThatLogs -> Appender -> MyClassThatLogs -> etc...
```

See also this SO post:
[logging/error handling inside a custom log4net appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261138/logging-error-handling-inside-a-custom-log4net-appender)